# trying to create a simple smile on android app using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

```
// Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
```

I am curious as to why when I import this into my GLSurfaceView class that my shape that i am ultimately wanting to display will not show up. I assumed it is this piece of code because when i take it out the app doesn't fail but with it in the code it fails.

Comment: I am trying to run openGL so that a basic triangle with appear in the app. As shown in the developers guide

Comment: It is hard to see what the question or the issue is. It looks like you are trying to move from ES1 to ES2... Try searching for "porting opengl es 1 to opengl es 2".